# google maps v3 filter json

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps

I have trawled the web looking for an answer to my question, unfortunately I didn't find a solution.  I want to read a json file to get the points to plot on map.  I also want to add 3 checkboxes to act as a filter.

I came across 2 examples but they don't seem to be reading from a json, instead they read from an xml file.  Hope someone can provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a JSON parser.  See http://www.json.org/js.html for more.

After the difference in how to parse (JSON vs. XML), the rest of the code should be the same.

Good luck!